# UIKit: Adding text to NavigationBar

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

I'm diving into UIKit and feel some misunderstanding after using SwiftUI. By following [course](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/2) from Paul Hudson there is some challenges in the end of the project. One of this it's try showing the player’s score in the navigation bar. I try to solve this case but closest solution that I found from Apple's documentation it's:

```
let scoreButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("Score: \(score)", comment: ""),
                                        style: .done,
                                        target: self,
                                        action: nil)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = scoreButton
```

But I think adding `Button` instead of simple `Text` is unnecessary, I don't need button behavior. Trying to add `UITextView()` to `NavigationBar` from storyboard did't work out...

Question: how to add text(better programmatically) to Navigation Bar? something like `.toolbarItem` with `ToolbarItemPlacement: .navigationBarTrailing` in SwiftUI. Is it possible or it's a UIKit restriction using only `rightBarButtonItem`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution how to add text to NavBar and yes it's restriction of UIKit thats you have to use `UIBarButtonItem`

```
let scoreView = UILabel()
scoreView.text = "Score: \(score)"
let scoreButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: scoreView)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = scoreButton
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [titleView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624935-titleview) property to show a text in the `NavigationBar`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
   
  let view = UIView()
  view.addSubview(titleLabel)
  view.addSubview(scoreLabel)
  navigationItem.titleView = view
}
```

Comment: Hey Abedalkareem and thx for the answer! But my goal is not adding the title of NavBar, I need to add one more View next to the title. Added screenshot to my question

Comment: I think you can use a UIView.

Something like
```
let view = UIView()
view.addSubview(titleLabel)
view.addSubview(scoreLabel)
navigationItem.titleView = view
```

This is from the documentation:
 (....Custom title views are centered on the navigation bar and may be resized to fit.)